# Simple country arithmetic

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Given the country sums below, what country sums up the last one?

EGYPT + HUNGARY = CHILE
GREECE + SPAIN = NEW ZEALAND
GREECE + PERU = JAPAN
SWITZERLAND + AUSTRIA = VIETNAM
SWITZERLAND + CUBA = SRI LANKA
CHILE + VIETNAM + SRI LANKA = NIGERIA
NEW ZEALAND + JAPAN + SRI LANKA = SÃO TOMÉ AND PRINCIPE
MAURITANIA + ANDORRA = URUGUAY
ERITREA + BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA = VANUATU
SÃO TOMÉ AND PRINCIPE + URUGUAY + AUSTRIA = BANGLADESH

**VIETNAM + NIGERIA + VANUATU = ??**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The addition adds the

> [country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes).

For example

> Egypt is +20 and Hungary is +36, this means that Egypt + Hungary is +56 which indeed corresponds to the country calling code of Chile.

This means that the answer is

> Vietnam (+84) + Nigeria (+234) + Vanuatu (+678) = **Kyrgyzstan** (+996).